# Why were the lyrics of "Let It Go" different in the "Frozen" movie compared to the Demi Lovato single?

Tags: music, disney, frozen

The lyrics of the "Let It Go" song differ quite a bit between the movie and the single:

Movie (Idina Menzel) :
https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/idinamenzel/letitgo.html

Single (Demi Lovato):
https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/demilovato/letitgo.html

Why is that?

Comment: This is not a first for Disney. The same thing happened regarding "Can You Feel the Love Tonight" from The Lion King. Sir Elton John's single version has really different lyrics in the verses.

Comment: A lot of songs in movies that are also released as single by the artist have differences between the two versions. I think it's because when composing the song for the movie the artist does it for the movie producers and they get to have a say in it, then when that's done the artist can do their own thing without movie-producer constraints and release it. All speculation though.

Comment: To meet a radio-friendly threshold, a song cannot be above a certain level of quality. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Let_It_Go_(Disney_song)):

> Anderson-Lopez and Lopez **also composed a simplified pop version** (with
>   shorter lyrics and background chorus) which was performed by actress
>   and singer Demi Lovato over the start of the film's closing credits.
>
> [...]
>
> Menzel's version was a single release, being promoted to adult
>   contemporary radio by Walt Disney Records in January 2014. **Disney's
>   music division** planned to release Lovato's version of the song
>   before Menzel's, as they **did not consider Menzel's version a
>   traditional pop song.**

The song's authors Robert Lopez and his wife Kristen Anderson-Lopez explain the differences in [this interview with SSN Insider](http://www.ssninsider.com/awards-spotlight-robert-lopez-kristen-anderson-lopez-make-beautiful-music-together-for-disneys-frozen/):

> **SSN:** Pop star and former Disney teen star Demi Lovato sings the song
>   over the end credits. Was she chosen because she is already in the
>   Disney fold? (Lovato is signed to the Disney Music Group’s Hollywood
>   Records)
>
> **Anderson-Lopez:** Because she is so damn talented. The Disney family
>   thing was very convenient, but honestly, she would have been at the
>   top of the list if she hadn’t been in the Disney family. “Heart
>   Attack” is one of my favorite songs of all time. Not everyone can sing
>   “Let It Go.” It’s not easy. She has the kind of voice that can.
>
> **SSN:** What’s the difference between the two versions?
>
> **Lopez:** The bridge. There’s a slight difference between the choruses.
>   It’s slightly rewritten for Demi Lovato. But the real change is the
>   part where Elsa is building the palace in the movie. It’s a totally
>   different section from the equivalent spot on the pop track.
>
> **Anderson-Lopez:** But both versions tell a story of transformation from
>   fear of letting your power go to letting it come out. Idina will
>   always be our Elsa, and she tells Elsa’s story so well, but it’s very
>   story based. Demi’s is a little more metaphorical where the beat
>   starts driving and driving, but you still get the same feeling of
>   releasing all of this pent-up energy.